# OR.SE Meetup at INFORMS?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Separate from the issue of [promoting OR.SE at INFORMS](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242/update-or-se-at-informs), I wanted to ask:

**Do we want to organize some sort of meetup at INFORMS?**

This is not something that SE would sponsor or support financially, so really this would just be a bunch of us agreeing to gather at a bar or restaurant at a certain day/time.

If there is interest, **is anyone willing to volunteer to take the lead on organizing it?** Maybe someone who is familiar with Seattle?

Answer (score 6):

Most years there is a reception at INFORMS for social media users. I think there is going to be one this year (not confirmed yet). If so, maybe we could meet there? Upside: There's likely to be beer, and there would definitely be a room reserved. Downside: Not everyone there will be an OR.SE participant (or even a social media user ... did I mention free beer?). Upside to the downside: Chance to promote the site?

Comment: I think this is a great idea. No one has come forward to volunteer to organize an OR.SE-centric event, so piggybacking off the social media event is a great idea. Do you know who is organizing it? I will try to get in touch with them.

Comment: This event is not happening this year, unfortunately. So, if we want to have a meetup, someone will have to take the lead in organizing it.

Comment: Did the not happening info come from Mary L.? Last I heard from her, she was planning to set it up (but not to attend it).

Comment: It came from Jeff Cohen, but Mary was cc'ed. This was in reference to the "INFORMS Online" reception, which I understood to be the same as the social media reception -- are they two different things?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that's the name Mary was using for the social media reception.