# OR.SE ribbons for INFORMS badges!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**We are going to have OR.SE ribbons to attach to INFORMS badges!** (You know -- this sort of thing:

[image]

They'll be available in the registration area, along with all the other ribbons, and will be self-serve.)

**What do we want them to say??** I'll suggest an idea below, but please post your own ideas. If you feel like making a suggestion about the ribbon color, feel free to do that as well.

We need to send the info to INFORMS **by Friday**.

I'll have some other updates about INFORMS in the next week or so, as well.

(Thanks to @EhsanK for the [suggestion](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/244/38) to have ribbons in the first place.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One idea:

## "OR Stack Exchanger"

Answer (score 3):

Color: perhaps as close as we can get to SE blue

Comment: With the 4 increasing shades...

Answer (score 2):

? $\rightarrow$ OR.SE $\rightarrow$ :)

Comment: This is cute. But I'm a little nervous about just using OR.SE since people won't know what that means. (OTOH many people won't even know what "Stack Exchange" means...)

Comment: Yeah I could see that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

For [INFORMS 2014](http://meetings2.informs.org/wordpress/sanfrancisco2014/2014/11/11/coin-or-at-informs-2014/) the badges with ribbons looked like this:

[image: INFORMS Badge with Ribbons]
<sub><sub>That's about the best that I could fix that poor image, others are welcome to try deconvolution and replace the photo with a sharper one.</sub></sub>

Larry's [answer](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/a/274/51) shows an image of OR.SE's [ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a9MUm.jpg).